# How to beautifully incorporate tables in texts/documents

Tags: page-layout

From time to time I have to write a small report and usually I end up having to present data in a table. Everytime I end up thinking that a table is an ugly looking rectangular box I wish I could leave out.

I don't have any degree in design, but I would like to know how I can make my tables look more smooth and blend better into the document. This has nothing to do with using `HTML` tables for layout. It is the aesthetically appearance of tables in text.

I know its subjective, but if you have seen or created a set of tables in a document somewhere, which you think looks good, it could be nice to see them and maybe get some inspiration from there.

Comment: What program are you using? that makes a HUGE difference in the answers we can give you. InDesign has about a thousand more tools than Word does for making things look nice.

Comment: At the moment, I'm using MS Word 2010. But I normally try to visualise what I want and then tweak all I can to get the correct result using the program at hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a few rules I follow myself...

- Always zebra stripe, never border
- Always different appearing header rows

The problem with most tables is, well, they look tabular. :) I try and diminish the appearance of a rectangle as much as possible and favor horizontals so they are more in line with simple text.

In addition, tabular data can often be reflected in a chart rather than a table. This is especially true of the table when it is small. So, when possible, I'll change the data to more of a graphic using a pie chart or some other chart rather than a boring old table. Of course, this depends greatly on the complexity of the data.

[image: vs.]

Ultimately, tables are merely a method to visually organize data. There are often many ways the data can be organized. "[Infographics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infographic)" are all about organizing tabular data into a visually appealing format. There's an unlimited way you can organize the data into an [infographic (samples)](http://www.google.com/search?q=infographics&safe=off&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=fFSSUdP1I-GSyQHTroDICQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1105&bih=1368).

There's a question here which maybe helpful discussing immediate vs. sequential data interpretation. Regardless of my efforts to do so, I can't seem to find that question.

Comment: Further thoughts: the typical spreadsheets-style lines for table cells are more useful for *entering* data than reading, it; the alternating row colors are useful for keeping place as you scan a line, but are not particularly helpful for smaller numbers of columns.